# Changing base color in sencha touch 2.2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sass, background-color

Recently i upgraded sencha framework to 2.2, facing problem with the scss.
Not able to change the base color($base-color) of the app.
follwing is the code i have in app.scss

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
$base-color: #008c99;
```

color change is not reflected any where in the app.

Is this the proper way to set the base color of the app, if not please let me know where i fumbled.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you receive any error when you compile your SASS?

Comment: Nope i didnt get any error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, just place the `"$base-color: #008c99"` above the `@import` statement. It should be placed before the import statement. Save and compile.. And then refresh to see the effect.

Comment: Any idea why it would not work for me?We write that in app.css right?

Comment: app.scss and you compile it with compass.. It gets updated in your app.css