# SCSS Theming in Sencha -$base-color

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sass

EDIT :

I really need it to work, if you are going to answer or reply, please read comment on question before, your point might have been covered already.

I'm trying to override the base variables of sencha to create a theme for my app

Here is my app.scss

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';


$base-color: #8bc531;
```

This one too did not work, has replied in comments. No need to link a non working answer and downvote again. Plus, good to know, the .scss file does compile correctly without errors.

```
$base-color: #8bc531;
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
```

Actually the file is longer and everything else works properly.
I'm only having problem with $base-color has it does not  change color at all of anything and it is suppose to affect most of the app's componenent at once...

Can someone explain me why it does not work has it should and has it is showed on the sencha websites...?

Comment: Check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184569/changing-base-color-in-sencha-touch-2-2

Comment: Still does not work :S

Comment: Which website shows that what you're doing is supposed to work?  Searching for the exact title of your question has this on the first page:  http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/theming-sencha-touch-with-sass/ (note variable first, imports after, exactly like the answer kevhender linked to) or http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch

Comment: I read those, see i also trued kev's answer... still nothing to work...  and your 1st link does not work.  Plus, before or after import seems to differ depending on the author, there seems to be no standard

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to compile your SASS through compass compile? Have you tried placing your code `$base-color` at the top before specifying `@import` statements? Little more info needed to help you further, please..

Comment: If you had read any of the comment you would have seen that I tried putting it at top. Plus, I do not have any compilling error else it would not work at all and I would have specified it already.

Comment: Thank to the one who added a link which was already given has an answer but was replied with "Still does not work". Feels like no body reads anything before being "mods".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of creating your project with trial version of ST.
The index file is not the same has when you buy it, in the trial one, it overides theming with their color, (uneditable) while in the paid version, this line is removed -_-'

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CarboZero</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #1985D0
    }

    #appLoadingIndicator {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -15px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        -webkit-animation-name: appLoadingIndicator;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-direction: linear;
    }

    #appLoadingIndicator > * {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        width: 30px;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes appLoadingIndicator{
        0% {
            opacity: 0.8
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0.8
        }
    }
</style>
<!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>
<script src="resources/AppLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="resources/ENG.js"></script>
<script src="resources/FR.js"></script>
<script src="resources/ESP.js"></script>
<script src="resources/GlobalVariables.js"></script>
<script src="resources/ProjectStorage.js"></script>
<script src="resources/Elements.js"></script>
<script src="resources/UnitConversion.js"></script>
<script src="resources/Types.js"></script>
<script src="resources/LanguageConversion.js"></script>
<script src="resources/ESPElement.js"></script>
<script src="resources/ENGElement.js"></script>
<script src="resources/FRElement.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="appLoadingIndicator">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```